# Inspecting a 'fitted sk-learn' pipeline still results in 'TFIdfVectorizer not fitted yet'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

this is an insecurity I have with sk-learn's Pipelines. Whenever I create a pipeline in sk-learn and do some predictions with this pipeline, I seem to come across the problem that I can't actually examine the *intermediate* steps of the pipeline. The predictions work, I get my scores, but if I want to get the 'feature importances' for instances, or examine what a tf-idf vectorizer's features are, the pipeline is claimed to not be fit (eventhough it was just recently used for inference and I already called training on it).

To take an example, calling `.fit()` on the following snippet from Scikit-learn's documentation from [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-compose-plot-column-transformer-py) works for prediction, but it claims the same unfitted problem when I want to check the pipeline's tfidf.

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    # Extract the subject & body
    ('subjectbody', SubjectBodyExtractor()),

    # Use ColumnTransformer to combine the features from subject and body
    ('union', ColumnTransformer(
        [
            # Pulling features from the post's subject line (first column)
            ('subject', TfidfVectorizer(min_df=50), 0),

            # Pipeline for standard bag-of-words model for body (second column)
            ('body_bow', Pipeline([
                ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
                ('best', TruncatedSVD(n_components=50)),
            ]), 1),

            # Pipeline for pulling ad hoc features from post's body
            ('body_stats', Pipeline([
                ('stats', TextStats()),  # returns a list of dicts
                ('vect', DictVectorizer()),  # list of dicts -> feature matrix
            ]), 1),
        ],

        # weight components in ColumnTransformer
        transformer_weights={
            'subject': 0.8,
            'body_bow': 0.5,
            'body_stats': 1.0,
        }
    )),

    # Use a SVC classifier on the combined features
    ('svc', LinearSVC(dual=False)),
], verbose=True)
```

After fitting the pipeline on the data (as is done in the link), when I try to access the vectorizer using

```
pipeline.named_steps.union.transformers[1][1].named_steps['tfidf'].get_feature_names()
```

it claims 'Vocabulary not fitted or provided'.

So, is this a misunderstanding I have of pipelines? Are we not supposed to access the intermediate steps? Or a setting maybe needs to be setup?

Comment: First, you have to be sure that `pipeline.named_steps.union.transformers[1][1].named_steps['tfidf']` addresses indeed the required one. Difficult for others to say without a [MCVE] with data. Why don't you adapt the example in the docs here? Shouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: Hi desertnaut, this pipeline is indeed accessible at that adress, I simple used the code as-is in the provided [binder link](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/0.22.X?urlpath=lab/tree/notebooks/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer.ipynb) from the linked URL. All I add is that line (for `pipeline.named_steps.etc`) right below the `pipeline.fit` in the provided binder url.

Comment: Quoting from [MCVE]: "Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included **in the question itself**" (emphasis in the original).

Comment: Alright, i'll keep that in mind for next time, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you need to access the transformers via `.transformers_`
So `pipeline.named_steps.union.transformers_[1][1].named_steps['tfidf'].get_feature_names()`

Comment: thanks! very useful. Any idea why this is the case?